# A top directory in a URL path returns a 404 error, will its subpages still be crawled?

Tags: seo, url, web-crawlers, 404

I found a site in which one of the directories in the URL path returns `404` error, but the subpages are still live.

**Example URL:** `https://shop.edurite.com/blogs/news/summer-activities`

In this URL

`https://shop.edurite.com/blogs`    -->  this will lead to a **404 error**

But

`https://shop.edurite.com/blogs/news/summer-activities` --> this is a **live page**

**My Questions:**

**1)** Will this URL be crawled by Google, without any glitch?

**2)** Would this be considered bad SEO? If yes then why?

Comment: An error status returned by a URL shouldn't impact the crawling of URLs containing that path. Unless there's a _robots.txt_ directive or server header disallowing the directory or page, the URL will be crawled if search engines can find it (i.e., it's linked to somewhere, exists in a sitemap, or is submitted directly using a tool like Fetch as Google...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google don't follow directories, it is not like Google type `ls` command and it show all the directory in your site. Google just follow links everywhere.

1. Internal/external links - For example, If I link to `stackexchange.com/blog/some-page/`, then Google will crawl only that webpage(`/some-page/`), it will not goint to crawl (`/blog/`) page, because it is not linked anywhere. If it is link somewhere then Google will crawl that URL as well. So Google just follow links to crawl all webpage on internet.
2. Sitemap - Sitemap also contain links. If Google simply rely on internal/external links then may be more than 10% webpages on internet will not going to index by Google. So Google suggest webmaster to create sitemap where you can list of all of your pages, so they will check your sitemap in regular time, and will index new URL which listed on sitemap.
3. Google submit URL - There are also tools on Google search console, where you can submit your links, and Google will crawl that.

So the whole internet world is crawled by links. They don't check sub/child pages to crawl. Even we can't know how many directories are there on specific website, it's may be given different permission to view it.

> Will this URL be crawled by Google, without any glitch?

If it is linked then it will be crawl by Googlebot. Crawling does not depends on child/sub-child pages. But in case, if `/blog/` directory is blocked on [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) then all of it's child pages will not be crawl, otherwise everything will be crawl.

> Would this be considered bad SEO? If yes then why?

No, it's not bad for whole website. If that page is not crawled by Googlebot, it means you can't see that URL in search result, and so on you won't get any search traffic on that page only. Other index pages can still get traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This was always of concern to us when making a website, and while I don't think we faced too many issues with pages not being indexed properly, we did feel that perhaps since the structure of the website was not perfect in such cases it would affect:

1. Navigation of the crawler
2. Domain credibility
3. Making a perfect breadcrumb

Because the above were assumptions/feelings and not proven, I can't say for sure.

One thing it definitely does affect though, is user navigation. Users expect URLs to work a certain way and without the mid level pages, it becomes difficult to understand navigation.

Comment: I see what you're saying about the "perfect breadcrumb" - although this could be worked around. But I don't see how this would affect "crawler navigation" or "domain credibility"?! And "user navigation" is debatable IMO - most users don't interact with the URL directly.

Comment: @w3dk I agree to some extent.

Unfortunately we never managed to fix those 404 hierarchies and hence I don't have evidence to show that it would give a rise to SEO traffic. :/

Comment: @w3dk I do think that if you have ~/X/Y/Z then the crawler would check ~/X/Y for related pages. To see if you are an authority on a topic in general.

For instance If you search for Australia, one of the top results is `https://www.lonelyplanet.com/australia`, and has a lot of highly ranking pages below it.

I completely agree that I'm more likely wrong than right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the link will be crawled by Google. And as i have checked, this is the main category URL https://shop.edurite.com/blogs/news/ and working fine too